# Writing text font in math subscripts

Tags: fonts, math-fonts, amsfonts

Is there any way to change the setup of amsfonts to show every subscript automathicaly in text fonts instead of the math default font? I have a long finished text in which every subindex is written simply as $a_b$, but I need to write as in $a_\text{b}$. Is there any shortcut, or do I need to do it manually?

Many thanks.

Comment: What about creating a macro `\newcommand{\subtext}[1]{_{\text{#1}}}` and then using `\subtext` instead of subscripts

Comment: Please note that `\text` is **not** a good choice for this. Consider what happens in `\textit{ $a_{\text{b}}$}` probably not what you expected. What exactly is text b in this case? If it is just a n upright text b, then use `\textrm{b}`. The `\text` command should never be trusted to provide upright output.

Comment: Additionally please do not use `$a_\text{b}$` it is a coincidence that is works, but there a no promises that it will continue to do so. Use braces `$a_{....}$`.

Comment: Please tell us whether you use pdfLaTeX, XeLaTeX, or LuaLaTeX to compile your document.

Comment: Hi! I'm using Overleaf

Comment: Sorry for not being clear enough earlier. I would like to know whether you employ pdfLaTeX, XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX to compile your document on the Overleaf platform.